# How to Assign muitiple coma separated values in a pandas data frame single column to separate but related columns

Tags: pandas

I have a simple pandas data frame where 'SM_platform' column contains multiple coma separated values like 1,2,7. Now I want to assign these values to separate related columns in the data frame.
ex : 1 should be added to column name FB,
2 to Twitter,
3 to Youtube..   etc ...Please advice how to do this task.
Appreciate your help. Thank you

```
   Age  SM_Platform
0   3   1, 2, 3, 7
1   3   1, 2, 3, 5, 7
2   1   1, 2, 3, 4
3   2   1, 2, 3, 4
4   1   1, 2
```

---

Comment: You can only use `SM_Platform` one time because the column is removed by `pop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), and borrowing the labels from [Corralien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523470/16746253)...

```
labels = {'1': 'Facebook',
          '2': 'Twitter',
          '3': 'Youtube',
          '4': 'Linkedin',
          '5': 'Instagram',
          '6': 'Pinterest',
          '7': 'TikTok'}

df = pd.concat([df, df['SM_Platform'].str.get_dummies(', ').rename(columns=labels)], axis=1)

   Age    SM_Platform  Facebook  Twitter  Youtube  Linkedin  Instagram  TikTok
0    3     1, 2, 3, 7         1        1        1         0          0       1
1    3  1, 2, 3, 5, 7         1        1        1         0          1       1
2    1     1, 2, 3, 4         1        1        1         1          0       0
3    2     1, 2, 3, 4         1        1        1         1          0       0
4    1           1, 2         1        1        0         0          0       0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. There is small error. There are additional unwanted columns also created .   'Facebook', '10', '11', '12',
       '12,13', '13', 'Twitter', '2, 3', 'Youtube', '3,8', 'Linkedin', '4,8',
       '4,8,13', 'Instagram', 'Pinterest', 'TikTok', '7,8', '8', '9', '9,13',
       'Weavers,twitch' .

Comment: It seems like your real data has extra responses not included in the question example (ex. '10', '11', '12', etc.). You'll need to account for these in some way. Some of your data in the `SM_Platform` column also seem to have an inconsistent delimiter, sometimes using comma+space`', '` and sometimes just comma `','`. You should clean up your column first, maybe `df['SM_Platform'] = df['SM_Platform'].str.replace('\s+','', regex=True)` to remove all spaces and then change the delimiter in get_dummies to just a comma `','`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will clean the data set first. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping of your platforms (1 -> Facebook, 2 -> Twitter, etc) then explode your column `SM_Platform` before replace numeric values by corresponding names. Add a `dummy` column and pivot your dataframe:

```
l = ['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Youtube', 'Linkedin',
     'Instagram', 'Pinterest', 'TikTok']
m = dict(enumerate(l, 1))

out = df.join(
    df['SM_Platform'].str.findall(r'\d+').explode().astype(int)
        .replace(m).reset_index().assign(dummy=1)
        .pivot_table('dummy', 'index', 'SM_Platform', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Age    SM_Platform  Facebook  Instagram  Linkedin  TikTok  Twitter  Youtube
0    3     1, 2, 3, 7         1          0         0       1        1        1
1    3  1, 2, 3, 5, 7         1          1         0       1        1        1
2    1     1, 2, 3, 4         1          0         1       0        1        1
3    2     1, 2, 3, 4         1          0         1       0        1        1
4    1           1, 2         1          0         0       0        1        0

>>> m
{1: 'Facebook',
 2: 'Twitter',
 3: 'Youtube',
 4: 'Linkedin',
 5: 'Instagram',
 6: 'Pinterest',
 7: 'TikTok'}
```

**Update**

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,\xa03'"

It seems you have invisible white space `'\xa0'` so it's probably better to extract all the digits.

Comment: Let me know if I understand correctly.

Comment: Hi Thanks you very much for you quick reply. Yes that is exactly what I want. but there is an error when I run that . "if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'SM_Platform' "   Appreciate your support : )

Comment: I update the original post with the error code hope its fine

Comment: I updated my answer. Now the `SM_Platform` column is not removed from your dataframe. Can you check that?

Comment: Thx for the update. Now it give a new error.. "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,\xa03'"  Any idea ?

Comment: @lasan13. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: These data frame actually from google form result sheet . There is no error now..... but its not creating new columns :(

Comment: What is the output of `df['SM_Platform'].str.findall(r'\d+').explode().astype(int)`?

Comment: It doesn't make any change to data frame

Comment: I know but what is the output of `print(df['SM_Platform'].str.findall(r'\d+').explode().astype(int))`

Comment: output like this " 0      1
0      2
0      3
0      7
1      1
      ..
431    7
432    1
432    2
432    3
432    4

Comment: it basically print first number in that column